# how can i tell if my SD.h and TMRpcm.h libraries are compatible?

Tags: c, compatibility, sd-card, nano

I am trying to get an Arduino Nano to play a WAV file, but it's not working.

The wiring looks good, and the code seems to be ok;

ChatGPT suggests that one of the possible reasons for the problem could be incompatibility of the libraries i've installed.  I have read the readme docs, but don't see any notes about that.

How could i check to see if the versions i've installed are compatible?
or, if these libraries are dependant on some other library that i neglected to install??

`your text`

the code uploads fine

i flip the switch and exactly nothing happens

It should play a WAV file. It doesn't

This is the uploaded code:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <TMRpcm.h>

#define SD_CS_PIN 10   // CS pin for the SD card reader
#define SWITCH_PIN 2   // Pin connected to the switch
#define LASER_PIN 3    // Pin connected to the laser
#define SD_MISO_PIN 12 // MISO pin
#define SD_MOSI_PIN 11 // MOSI pin
#define SD_SCK_PIN 13  // SCK pin
TMRpcm audio;

void setup() {
pinMode(SWITCH_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);  // Enable the internal pull-up resistor
audio.speakerPin = 5;  // Set the speaker pin (any available PWM pin)
Serial.begin(9600);

if (!SD.begin(SD_CS_PIN)) {
Serial.println("SD card initialization failed!");
while (1);
}

audio.setVolume(5);  // Set the volume (0 to 7)
}

void loop() {
if (digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN) == LOW) {
playSound("mp3/tos_phaser_7_01.wav");  // Play the WAV file when the switch is pressed
}
}

void playSound(const char* filename) {
if (audio.isPlaying()) {
audio.stopPlayback();
}
audio.play(filename);
}
```